# fstring gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm trying to learn python using Python Crash Course 2ND EDITION so it's not the latest edition but it's using Python 3.6 i guess. my python version is 3.10.11

this is my code:

```
names = ['sepehr', 'farzad', 'mahan', 'arting', 'saeed']
message = f"greeting my dear friend ! {names [0].title()}".
print (message)
```

when i try to run the code in cmd i get this:

```
  File "M:\My codes\Python_Crash_course\Chapter-3\greetings.py", line 2
    message = f"greeting my dear friend ! {names [0].title()}".
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks !

(i tried rewriteng the code but i got the same result)

Comment: This isn't English - you're not supposed to have a period at the end.

Comment: (Or if you wanted a period in the message, it goes *inside* the string literal.)

Comment: If you quote the error message, please quote the *complete* error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove "." at the end of message = line and it should work

```
message = f"greeting my dear friend ! {names [0].title()}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was the problem it's working fine now. I can't believe how distracted I am